# How to apply a function to a list while changing a specific argument which sets the output file name

Tags: r, function, apply, lapply, sapply

My question is a general one. How would you apply the below function (hypothetical in this case) to two lists: list_1 and list_2 in R. The lists are equally long and they are paired.

```
function(argument1, argument2) # where argument one should be applied to list_1 and argument2 should be applied to list_2
```

A reproducible example can be:

```
as.list(paste0("raster", seq(1:10))) -> list_1        # A made-up list of raster names. In real life, this should be a list of rasters.
as.list(paste0("file", seq(1:10), ".tif")) -> list_2  # A made-up list of file names.

library(gdalUtils)

gdal_translate(src_dataset =, dst_dataset = )
# where src_dataset argument should be applied to list_1 and dst_dataset argument should be applied to list_2
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example with expected output.

Comment: You can use `Map` function. `Map(function(argument1, argument2) bodyOfTheFunction, list_1, list_2)`

Comment: A reproducible example has been added.

Answer (score 0):

`mapply` function was what I was looking for.

```
# Define a function to be applied to the lists.
func2 <- function(x, y){
  gdal_translate(src_dataset = x, dst_dataset = y)
}
# Apply the function to the lists.
mapply(FUN = func2, list_1, list_2)
```